# Is there any perfomance coefficient or proportions for Rest Api

Tags: performance, rest

How can we measure Rest Api's Performance?

You may say, I could use JMeter to test response time or change the concurrency level and observe the result. However, I don't want to observe something, I want to use a number, just a number to express them all. This number should include the details like response time, payload, and code complexity. Maybe it is a function or model that returns a result.

What I actually need is comparing the rest API's without having any subjectivities. It sounds like a score.

In a nutshell, how can I generate a score from the api's performances results

Comment: This is going to be very subjective as you will need to include different factors and decide how much, or how little, they influence the result and will depend on what you consider important.

Comment: simple answer would be: no!
better answer: see first comment!